# Elixir GenServer parallel handle_call

Tags: elixir, gen-server

There is an application on the Phoenix Framework.

There is a need for GenServer, which will check some values.

Validation of these values is started from the controller (a request comes from the client, the GenServer value checks, the client receives a response).

Once handle_call is synchronous, then what happens when 10 clients call 10 calls handle_call at a time? All 10 calls will be processed in parallel or in the order of the queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GenServer will process only single call other messages will be queued in mailbox. You can allow this if there is need for synchronous process but you have to think about mailbox, it could pile up soon on heavier load and kill VM probably without any warning.

Did you consider using Task instead?

Comment: Thank you. So using GenServer is a bad idea for this task. The problem is that I need to make several calls to a third-party API, and process and return the result to the client. Apparently, I need to use Task, or make these calls right in the request processing thread from the client

Comment: Well, here is what could guide you to make decision when to use each. If you have short task (just one call and then response then use Task) but when it is some long running process, you should definitely use GenServer and build supervision tree around such. But you need to think do you really really need synchronous call? The consumer can either to subscribe to channel or to try each 5 seconds to fetch result using some "correlation id"